# Where can I fix control-clicking in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Some time ago I was messing around with keyboard shortcuts, now I can't use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 'click' to open links in new tabs. It's a minor inconvenience, but one that I actually find I need a lot. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 'clicking 'links in browsers doesn't do anything. v. 13.10 and I'm using Unity.

Comment: is this for all browsers??
Does the middle mouse button still works for opening a link in a new tab?

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden -- The middle mouse button still works and right-clicking still fails to open links in new tabs in all browsers.

Comment: strange, it could be a compiz problem but not one I've ever encountered.
You could try the compiz config settings manager ( https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/ ) and reset your compiz settings back to default.
See if that'll work. I'm also reading something about a rare bug where the left alt key + left mouse click opens a new tab.

I believe there is even an option to change ctrl click to a middle mouse button click in compizconfig settings manager if nothing else works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it, I am using XUBUNTU and I enabled the option to use my CONTROL(ctrl) key to grab and move windows. which is in Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility -> Key used to grab and move windows.